# PHP contact box script sends email on page load

Tags: php, html

so I'm trying to get a contact box working, and it does work. But whenever somebody clicks on the contact page, it automatically sends a blank email. How do  stop this?!

PHP

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "iamtomalmond@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html'> Return Home</a>";
?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST">
<p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
<p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
<p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Thanks in advance :(

Answer (score 5):

You need to check if a `POST` request was made and only execute the mailing code if that is the case:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  // your php code (first block in your question)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're calling `mail()` on page load.  If you only want to do it when the form is submitted (which I suspect), check to see if some of your `$_POST` variables exist prior to calling `mail()`.

```
if (isset($_POST['foo']))
{
     //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your page must test for the content of the `$_POST` array before sending the email:

```
<?php
   if (!is_empty($_POST)) {
      if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {
          // code to send email as in your question code snippet
      } else {
          // optionally display an error message
      }
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: actually checking first if indeed there's POST request received is the right way to handle at the outermost bracket, see @jeroen answer.